# Ajuda - C# como atualizar comboBox? tipo autocomplete

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Primeiramente eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema em C# e usando Sql Server como banco.

Eu gostaria de realizar a seguinte tarefa:
Quando algo for digitado no comboBox eu atualizo o próprio, por meio de uma pesquisa no banco, exemplo:

Eu digito A no comboBox e carrega ele com o retorno do selecte.

Outro Exemplo: Igual a busca do google, americanas, extra e etc. Estilo um autocomplete, sendo que é necessário o uso do comboBox, pois nele eu tenho que trazer o nome no display e o código no value do comboBox.

Estilo um autocomplete, mas eu preciso que seja um comboBox pois nele eu trago junto um código.

Eu programei da seguinte forma:

exe:

```
comboBox.DataSource = dataTable;
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Nome";
comboBox.ValueMember = "codigo;
```

Dentro do TextChanged do comboBox.

O select esta certo e o dataTable ta certo, mas estou tendo o seguinte problema o comboBox pega a primeira linha que retorna e não deixa eu continua digitando, nem altera para registro de baixo (OBS: Retorna mais de uma linha) nem ao menos ele mostra a lista, simplesmente "trava" no primeira linha.

Eu não sei se tem que configura alguma propriedade do comboBox ou realizar em um evento especifico ...

Primeiramente eu tinha feito um autocomplete em um textBox, funciona mas eu não consigo pega o código da opção é selecionado.

E eu não queria carrega o comboBox com todos os registros. Pra não fica algo pesado.

Mais especificamente eu estou fazendo um form relacionado a venda, e eu que pesquisa o cliente dessa forma. Nem sei se tem como.

Desde já fico grato com qualquer sugestão.

Atualização --

códio do textChanged do comboBox

```
    private void cmbNome_Cliente_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        cliente.Nome = cmbNome_Cliente.Text;
        cliente.Razao_social = cmbNome_Cliente.Text;


        cmbNome_Cliente.DataSource = cliente.CarregaClienteNome(); "Isso retorna um dataTable"
        cmbNome_Cliente.DisplayMember = "Nome - Razao Social";
        cmbNome_Cliente.ValueMember = "Código";
    }
```

//Pesquisar Cliente para o ComboBox pelo nome ##atualizado

```
    public DataTable CarregaClienteNome()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            cmd.CommandText = "select top(5) cli.cod_cliente as Código, ";
            cmd.CommandText += "(case when pes.cod_tipo_pessoa = 1 then Nome else Razao_Social end) as 'Nome - Razao Social' ";
            cmd.CommandText += "from tab_Pessoa pes ";
            cmd.CommandText += "inner join tab_Cliente cli on pes.cod_pessoa = cli.cod_pessoa ";
            cmd.CommandText += "where pes.nome like '" + Nome + "%' or pes.razao_social like '" + Razao_social + "%'";
            cmd.CommandText += " order by 'Nome - Razao Social'";

            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

//Autocomplete - teste que eu fiz com autocomplete em um textBox, ele esta funcionando. Porem não consigo obter o código

```
private void txtTeste_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();

        cliente.Nome = txtTeste.Text;
        cliente.Razao_social = txtTeste.Text;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        dt =cliente.CarregaClienteNome();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            source.Add(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
        }


        txtTeste.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;            

    }
```

Comment: mostra o código completo do "TextChanged" da combobox

Comment: Porque não usa um textBox com comboBox, escreve em um, mostra em outro?

Comment: Outro detalhe, tive um problema parecido quando eu preencheia alguns campos que alteravam o comboBox, ele não era atualizado... Tente colocar comboBox1.DataSource = null; antes de atribuir o retorno da função a ele e se você estiver usando um DataTable na função CarregaClienteNome() coloque nomeDataTabledtResultado.Clear(); antes de preenche-lo. e ao final, embaixo de cmbNome_Cliente.ValueMember = "cod_cliente"; coloque comboBox1.Refresh();

Comment: Seria interessante colocar o código da CarregaClienteNome();

Comment: Vi que você estava com dificuldade em pegar a seleção do autoComplete, Posso te ajudar. acho que ficaria melhor com o textobox e o autoComplete. O que acha?

Comment: O autoComplete tem um seguinte problema eu não consigo pega o código do cliente selecionado.

Comment: Na primeira vez eu fiz com autocomplete no textBox, a lógica é aquela porem não consigo obter o código.

Comment: Marconi se tiver alguma forma de se obter o código utilizando o autocomplete, seria bem útil. Eu atualizei o post com um teste que eu tinha feito utilizando o autocomplete em um textBox.

Comment: Por que não usa o autocomplete do Jquery Ui.
Olha o exemplo que coloquei.
Se precisar de ajuda pode me adicionar no skype.
marconi.barroso92

Answer (score 3):

A pedido do amigo @LuisFelipeMicaideJesus vou colocar um exemplo usando `autoComplete`.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtPesquisarHipotese" runat="server" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfPesquisarHipotese" runat="server" Value="" />
```

txtPesquisarHipotese ==> Textbox que irá colocar o AutoComplete.

hdfPesquisarHipotese ==> hiden que irá esconder a Seleção do usuário.

Quando uso a função `select` eu pego o valor que o usuário selecionou e guardo no HiddenField.

Se precisar de mais detalhes, especifique nos comentarios que eu edito a resposta.

```
$(function () {
    $("#<%=txtPesquisarHipotese.ClientID%>").autocomplete(
                    {
                        source: function (request, response) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("../ws/AutoComplete.asmx/GetEscopo")%>',
                                data: JSON.stringify({
                                    'prefixText': request.term
                                }),
                                dataType: "json",
                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                success: function (data) {
                                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                        return {
                                            label: item.split('#')[1],
                                            val: item.split('#')[0]
                                        }
                                    }))
                                },
                                error: function (response) {
                                    alert(response.responseText);
                                },
                                failure: function (response) {
                                    alert(response.responseText);
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        select: function (e, i) {
                            $("#<%=hdfPesquisarHipotese.ClientID%>").val(i.item.val);
                        },
                        minLength: 1
                    });
});
```

Código dentro do meu aquivo .asmx
Obs: Se você quiser pode usar a url para acessar  um WebMethod dentro de sua página.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string[] GetEscopo(string prefixText)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        List<string> resultado = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            using (conn = new SqlConnection(Conexao))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Escopo from Escopos where Escopos.Escopo like @prefixText group by Escopo order by Escopo", conn);
                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@prefixText", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["@prefixText"].Value = "%" + prefixText + "%";
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        resultado.Add(dr["Escopo"].ToString());
                    }
                    dr.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        return resultado.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: @Luis Felipe Micai de Jesus Deu certo?