# Como desenvolver um ComboBox que atualiza decorrente do que é escrito no próprio C#

Tags: c#, combobox

Primeiramente o cenário:

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em C# com o banco SQL Server.
No momento me encontro com o seguinte problema: De maneira resumida estou desenvolvendo um form de Venda, e nele eu tenho um comboBox onde trago o nome dos clientes.

E nesse comboBox eu gostaria que os itens que ele tem se atualizacem decorrente do que é escrito no próprio. Exe: Igual a busca do google, americanas, extra e etc.
Estilo um autocomplete, sendo que é necessário o uso do comboBox, pois nele eu tenho que trazer o nome no display e o código no value do comboBox.

Eu já fiz um post aqui com esse mesmo problema mas ninguém conseguiu me responder.

[Ajuda - C# como atualizar comboBox? tipo autocomplete](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47285/ajuda-c-como-atualizar-combobox-tipo-autocomplete)

Desde já agradeço qualquer sugestão.

Comment: Vou votar para fechar e colocar uma recompensa na pergunta.

Comment: Desculpa se eu fiz algo de errado sou novo e o post era antigo e ninguém respondeu, não sabia como atualiza de forma que responde-se por isso criei esse. se for o caso posso apaga.